# How to write stored procedures in Wampserver to run Automatically

Tags: mysql

I didn't know anything about Stored procedures. unfortunately I have to run a stored procedure automatically.
I have a table called **pass** and I want to update status as **cancelled** at the end of the day automatically.  I'm using phpmyadmin in wampserver.

I have already tried some codes but I don't know this code is correct and how to set execution automatically.

here is my code,

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE MyTask
 AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
    GO
    --  For executing the stored procedure at 1:00 A.M
    declare @delayTime nvarchar(50)
    set @delayTime = '01:00'

    while 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        waitfor time @delayTime 
        BEGIN
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateDuration] AS
    UPDATE pass SET status = 'Cancelled' WHERE duration_type='Daily' && duration = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        --Name for the stored proceduce you want to call on regular bases
        execute [gatepass].[dbo].[updateDuration];
        END
    END
END
```

It says that to put below code, but I don't know where to put these.

```
-- Sets stored procedure for automatic execution.
sp_procoption    @ProcName = 'MyTask',
                @OptionName = 'startup',
                @OptionValue = 'on'
```

Answer (score 0):

***Method #1 - Batching***

Create a script named runMyTask.sql or whatever you want.

That script should have your SQL to run the stored procedure:

```
-- Sets stored procedure for automatic execution.
CALL sp_procoption('MyTask','startup', 'on');
```

Then you need a batch script which you might name runMyTask.bat.

In the .bat file you add the line that runs the mysql.exe command line tool and redirects the contents of the runMyTask.sql file along the lines of something like

```
C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql..../bin/mysql -u root --password=your_password database_name < C:/path/to/runMyTask.sql
```

When you have tested that the batch script runs correctly from the windows cmd shell, [set it up in the scheduler](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7).

***Method #2 MySQL - Event Scheduler***

To use [the event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html) you'll need to first make sure you it's enabled on the server.  By default it is not.  From the aforementioned mysql command line, login as root.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

After you turn it on, run a `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` command and you should see a line similar to this one, showing the user event_scheduler owning a process.

```
| 10729276 | event_scheduler | localhost       | NULL       | Daemon  |    4 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL             |    0.000 |
```

At this point you can add "events". To add your stored procedure run as an event, once an hour:

```
USE your_db;

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS EventRunMyTask 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR 
ENABLE 
DO CALL sp_procoption('MyTask','startup', 'on');
```

If everything goes well you should be able to see information about the scheduled job using `SHOW EVENTS;`

Comment: thank you for answer but I want to schedule in Database since I host that.

Comment: Your question made no made no mention of that.  I added information about the mysql event scheduler, as well as improved the portion on running a sproc using CALL, which I glossed over previously.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it. I'll look for the answer

Comment: Did you re-read my answer?  I provided a new section that shows how to use the mysql event scheduler.